# How to represent web component tags in Kotlin html frameworks?

Tags: html, kotlin, web-frameworks

Kotlin has frameworks to represent html, such as [kotlinx](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html). How can I represent web component tags in such frameworks? For instance, if I want to use Polymer components, do I have to extend these frameworks to include every Polymer component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [Customize Kotlinx](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Micro-templating-and-DSL-customizing) (To create a [Custom Tag](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Micro-templating-and-DSL-customizing#introduce-custom-tag)). For a tag called `dicom-editor` to be used inside `divs`:

```
class DicomEditor(consumer: TagConsumer<*>) :
        HTMLTag("dicom-editor", consumer, emptyMap(),
                inlineTag = true,
                emptyTag = false), 
        HtmlInlineTag {}

fun DIV.dicom_editor(block: DicomEditor.() -> Unit = {}) {
    DicomEditor(consumer).visit(block)
}
...
div{
    dicom_editor {
        onMouseDownFunction = {_ ->
            window.alert("Dicom Editor")
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, the `dicom_editor` call includes a callback for the mouse down event. You can also add atributes: `attributes["data-toggle"] = "dropdown"`

You can add attributes as fields:

```
class DicomEditor(consumer: TagConsumer<*>) :
        HTMLTag("dicom-editor", consumer, emptyMap(),
                inlineTag = true,
                emptyTag = false), 
        HtmlInlineTag {
            var data_toggle: String = ""
                set(x) {attributes["data-toggle"] = x}
        }

fun DIV.dicom_editor(block: DicomEditor.() -> Unit = {}) {
    DicomEditor(consumer).visit(block)
}
...
div{
    dicom_editor {
        data_toggle = "dropdown"
    }
}
```

In the Kotlin code, you have to use `_` in the place of `-` or you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use [Vaadin 10](https://vaadin.com/flow) to control (Polymer-based) web components from server-side Java. Events are fully supported, please read the docs on how to [wrap Web Component in a Java API](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/web-components/integrating-a-web-component.html).

There is a Kotlin integration with Vaadin 10 ready:

- The [Vaadin-on-Kotlin](http://www.vaadinonkotlin.eu/) (VoK) framework; there are nice [guides](http://www.vaadinonkotlin.eu/vok-guides.html) for Vaadin 10 to get you started there.
- An example project built on VoK: [Vaadin-Kotlin-PWA](https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin-kotlin-pwa). This project demoes usage of [AppLayout](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout) Web Component: [AppLayout.kt](https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin-kotlin-pwa/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/vaadin/pwademo/components/AppLayout.kt).

The example code which uses the AppLayout layout and shows the basic page:

```
@BodySize(width = "100vw", height = "100vh")
@HtmlImport("frontend://styles.html")
@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes")
@Theme(Lumo::class)
class MainLayout : AppHeaderLayout(), RouterLayout {
    private val content: Div
    init {
        appHeader {
            appToolbar {
                title.text = "Vaadin Kotlin PWA Demo"
                paperIconButton(VaadinIcons.FILE_REMOVE) {
                    addClickListener {
                        Notification.show("A toast!", 3000, Notification.Position.BOTTOM_CENTER)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        appDrawer {
            navMenuItem(VaadinIcons.LIST, "Task List")
            navMenuItem(VaadinIcons.COG, "Settings")
            navMenuItem(VaadinIcons.QUESTION, "About")
        }
        content = div {
            setSizeFull(); classNames.add("app-content")
        }
    }

    override fun showRouterLayoutContent(content: HasElement) {
        this.content.element.appendChild(content.element)
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of VoK

Answer (score 0):

You can create XSD file for your components and generate them automatically. It's exactly how kotlinx do it.

Generator is part of the project. Check it out here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/tree/master/generate

There is also the source XSD file for HTML5 in resource folder:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/blob/master/generate/src/main/resources/html_5.xsd

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: Using information from [Kotlix Customizing DSL](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Micro-templating-and-DSL-customizing) I was almost able to create a new tag. However, Korlinx [do not support events](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Events) yet. Can anybody suggest another framework?